# How to access BSON data "cells" in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, bson

I have a problem:

In Meteor, I would like to be able to first fetch data from mongodb and then be able to update/edit the fetched data before returning it to the template.

So for example I have movies in the database in the following format:

```
{ name: "...", released: "..." }
```

In the code i would do something like this:

```
var movie = Movies.findOne({name: "Inception"});
```

Then I would like to get and edit the "release" data from the movie -variable. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [transform](http://docs.meteor.com/#collections):

```
return Movies.find({}, {transform:function(movie) {
    if(movie.release) movie.release = movie.release + " _ This has been appended to release".
    return movie;
});
```